For a ring hom $\phi: A \to B$, is it always true that $B \otimes_A A/I \cong B/\phi(I)B$?
I am wondering if it is always true that for $\phi: A \to B$ some unital ring homomorphism, we have that $B \otimes_A A/I \cong B/\phi(I)B$. First, I defined a map $B \times A/I \to B/\phi(I)B$ by
$$(b,a) \mapsto b\phi(a)$$ and showed that that this is well defined and bilinear, so we obtain a map
$$B \otimes_A A/I \to B/\phi(I)B$$
by the universal property of tensor products. For this second map, I am able to show surjectivity, but I am having trouble showing injectivity. Here is my issue: say we have
$$
 b \otimes a \mapsto b \phi(a) \in \phi(I)B
$$
I want to be able to say that $a \in I$ so that $b \otimes a = 0$, but I am unable to since $\phi(a) \in \phi(I)$ does not imply $a \in I$, so I am wondering how I could move past this roadblock.

Duplicate question. Also holds for modules.

Isomorphism = invertible morphism. You need to construct an inverse morphism. Don't bother about showing injectivity.

Thanks, could you please link the duplicate question?

Using site search for one minute did the job. Please always try to do this before asking (basic) questions. (With "basic" I am not claiming that it must be easy when you are new to the topic. I mean that it's a basic ingredient in the theory and hence used and proven in many places. Like the infinitude of primes for example.)

Thanks, I did Google the question and also use the "similar questions" functionality on the questions draft page, but I did not see the question you linked for some reason

The site search is right there in the top. I entered things like tensor product A/I. You can also always try https://approach0.xyz

Thanks, I'll definitely try that next time
